# Transfer files via command line to Azure VM with Comcast as ISP

Tags: azure, network-share

We've recently switched to using Azure VMs for our build PC, and I have a batch script that I used previously to do a bunch of copying, moving, uploading, etc. I used "net use..." for this, but that seems to be no longer valid as I can't connect to the file share because Comcast blocks ingoing & outgoing for port 445, which is what the Azure file share uses.

What other options do I have to do this without hand-copying files through an RDP session every time?

Answer (score 1):

Setup a VPN between your office and your Azure system.

Comment: This seems like it would allow the most flexibility. Is there any VPN built-in to Azure at all, do you know? EDIT: I did find this tutorial that looks promising: http://www.cloudcomputingadmin.com/articles-tutorials/windows-azure/configure-client-based-remote-access-vpn-windows-azure-virtual-networks.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you moving files in to Azure for archive or for an application to use?

Have you consider using Azure Storage Explorer to move files into Azure Blob storage:

http://storageexplorer.com/

or products like visual studio can interact with Azure storage too.

Comment: Yeah, It's to copy files in that will be used to build InstallShield exe's. Do these suggestions allow me to access files from my batch script, move them around, delete them, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup Windows Azure (Server 2012) as an SSTP and L2TP VPN Provider, your client PC connects to this VPN. I test it in my lab, it works for me. I could mount file share even though ISP block 445 Port. More information about how to setup Azure Windows as a VPN provider, please refer to the [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/notime/2013/06/01/how-to-setup-windows-azure-server-2012-as-an-sstp-and-l2tp-vpn-provider/).

Also, you could refer to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/822375/azure-file-share-from-on-prem) which is similar to you.

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a shot in the next day or two...got busy distracted with some other stuff currently :/

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I've been so slammed with other stuff I still haven't had time to try this. I also have to make sure that paying more for something like this is ok with the chief first ;).

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner, but I ended up setting up Perforce on the server to be able to grab the files that I had originally wanted to transfer from my local PC. This works great, and was super simple.

Comment: If possible, you could share your experience to this, it maybe help more people.